# Аналогия va_args в java, и их переброс

Tags: java, java-8, varargs

Ребят, давно на Java не писал, уже базовый синтаксис забывать начал.

Подскажите пожалуйста как аналог Си va_args передать методу наследнику? В моём случае String.format, использую 8й JDK.

```java
public void smsMapStringFmt(String format, Object ...arguments) { // это помню
    smsMapString(String.format(format, ...arguments)); // тут буксую..
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае достаточно убрать многоточие при вызове:

```java
smsMapString(String.format(format, arguments));
```

---

При этом никто не мешает добавить новые аргументы при вызове, в том числе и как массив, тогда изменится наполнение массива вараргов внутри вызываемой функции:

```java
smsMapStringFmt("Test: %s - %s %n", "hip", "hop");

public void smsMapStringFmt(String format, Object ...arguments) {

    String[] args = {"foo", "bar"};

    // передаётся строки из массива arguments
    smsMapString(String.format(format, arguments)); // "hip", "hop"

    // передаются массивы
    smsMapString(String.format(format, arguments, args)); // {"hip", "hop"}, {"foo", "bar"}

    // передаётся массив и строка
    smsMapString(String.format(format, arguments, "hello")); // {"hip", "hop"}, "hello"
}
```

Comment: А ларчик просто открывался. А я уже полез в дебри рефлексии и прочего бреда. =) Спасибо!